# LoadBalancer SSL policy is not updated after helm changes GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm, load-balancing

I am applying the SSL policy using `FrontendConfig` in helm k8s

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: FrontendConfig
metadata:
  name: test-preview
spec:
  sslPolicy: {{ .Values.frontendConfig.sslPolicy }}
```

ingress.yaml

```
# Source: test/templates/ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: test-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test-preview
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-preview
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "stable"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: External
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: some-cert
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: test-preview
    networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: test-preview
```

It is applied successfully, but when I remove annotation and frontendConfig the LoadBalancer itself does not change and still attached to this SSL policy, not to the default.
So the frontendConfig even does not exist, and Ingress does not have the `networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig` annotation.

Comment: I've also obtained, that when I am changing the policy to default it does not reattaches as well.